Prisma Seed Command Fails with TypeScript File Extension Error
I'm trying to seed my database using Prisma's official CLI, but I'm encountering an unexpected error when running npx prisma db seed. My project was set up using the official Prisma CLI, and I'm following their documentation, yet I'm getting a file extension error that seems bizarre.
Error message
TypeError: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /path/to/prisma/seed.ts
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:218:9)
    ...

My package.json Seed Configuration:
"prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node prisma/seed.ts"
}

However, It does work with when installing tsx and modifying it to:
"prisma": {
    "seed": "tsx prisma/seed.ts"
}

I'm frustrated because I’m using Prisma's official CLI and documentation. Why do I have to tweak the setup to make it work? Shouldn't it work out of the box?
